# Best way to create a C String

Tags: c++, c, string

I'm currently using

```
char *thisvar = "stringcontenthere";
```

to declare a string in C.

Is this the best way to declare a string in C?

And how about generating a C-String from C++-Strings?

Comment: Note that this should be `const char *thisvar = "stringcontenthere";` (additional `const`). There is an implicit `const`-removing conversion from a string literal to `char*`, but that's deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Also note that `char* foo;` __defines__ a variable (of type `char*`) and `char* foo="bar";` __defines and initializes__ a variable. A __declaration__ would be `extern char* foo;`. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/1410632#1410632 for what's a definition and what's a declaration.)

Comment: You should clarify whether or not you are interested in C++ as well, as the C++ tag does not find any notice in the question nor the subject.

Answer (score 16):

In C it depends on how you'll use the string:

- named constant: your `char* str = "string";` method is ok (but should be `char const*`)
- data to be passed to subfunction, but will not not used after the calling function returns:
  `char str[] = "string";`
- data that will be used after the function it is declared in exits: `char* str = strdup("string");`, and make sure it gets `free`d eventually.

if this doesnt cover it, try adding more detail to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *thisvar="stringcontenthere";
```

Comment: It must read thisvar = "stringcontenthere" and it should be const char*

Comment: Then is should be named `const char *thisconst="stringcontenthere";` SCNR;

Answer (score 1):

As other suggested, and I you want to "do it" the `C++` way, use a `std::string`.

If you somehow need a `C-string`, `std::string` has a method that gives a `const char*`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void dummyFunction(const char* str)
{
  // Do something
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  std::string str = "hello world!";

  dummyFunction(str.c_str());

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For ASCII encoded strings see paragraphs C and C++. For unicode encoded strings see last paragraph.

### C:

As David pointed out it depends on how to use the string in C:

- as a constant then: `const char s[] = "Hello World";`
- as a string containing variable data then: `char s[] = "Hello World";`
- as a data array `char *data`; Initialization then should be customized.

Please note in C there are all Strings Null-terminated, that means the definition of e.g. `char s[] = "foo";` implicitly includes a `NULL` character at the end `s[3]='\0'`.

Also please note the subtile difference between `char *s` and `char s[]` which might often behave the same but sometimes not! (see [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)) for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char s[] = "123456789123456789123456789";
  char *t = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char) * 28 );
  for( size_t i = 0; i < 28; ++i )
      t[ i ] = 'j';
  printf( "%lu\n", sizeof(s) );
  printf( "%lu\n", sizeof(t) );
  printf( "%s\n", s );
  printf( "%s\n", t );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So I recommend to use char arrays whenever you use them as strings and char pointers whenever you use them as data array.

### C++:

In C++ there is an own string data type: `std::string`. If you just need to have a C-String version of a std::string (e.g. using some C-API) just use the `c_str()` member:

```
std::string s = "Hello World";
your_c_call( s.c_str(), ... );
```

### Unicode:

I you want to have unicode strings then you should really go with something like

```
char utf8String[] = u8"Hello World";
```

and try not to use `wchar_t` whenever possible. See this excellent article on that issue: http://www.nubaria.com/en/blog/?p=289. Please not that there is also unicode support for C++. But generally I am tempted to say that you should go with normal characters as far as you can. Interesting resource on that: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this C or C++? In C++ you should use [`std::string`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/):

```
std::string aString("stringcontenthere");
```